# Access Denied Error in Admin Panel - Cart Mart (Multivendor Marketplace) - Magento 1.9.X

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting access denied error for 3 Tabs in admin panel.

```
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <vendor>
                        <title>Vendor</title>
                        <children>                                
                            <orders>
                                <title>Orders</title>
                            </orders>
                            <transaction>
                                <title>Transactions</title>
                            </transaction>
                            <review>
                                <title>Reviews</title>
                            </review>
                        </children>
                    </vendor>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <cartmart>
                                        <title>Cart Mart Section</title>
                                    </cartmart>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `_isAllowed()` method in orders, transactions, reviews Controllers files.

```
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```